# Fastening a Nut on threaded rod from the middle

Tags: fasteners

Does there exist any type of Nut, that can be screwed on a threaded rod that can slipped in without having to go to the ends of the threaded rod?  I can sort of imagine a Nut that was a `U` shape instead of `O` shape, or perhaps two `C` shapes that could interlock some how.  Does anything like this exist?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Granger Supply makes two different types:

[image]

[image: Caddy Threaded Rod Nut]

The round one is called A Steel Shaft Collar,two piece, Threaded . The second one is called a "CADDY THREADED ROD NUT". They come in a number of sizes.

Comment: Please include what its actually called.

Comment: The round one is called  A Steel Shaft Collar, Clamp, Threaded . The second one is called a  "CADDY THREADED ROD NUT".  They come in a number of sizes.

Comment: Also Dave, if you want a Rube Goldberg solution, you can cut a nut in half with a hack saw and then use a hose clamp to clamp the nut around the threaded rod. This works for light to medium applications.

Comment: @JACK My god lol.

Comment: @DKNguyen  LOL  You don't like my Rube Goldberg solution??  lol

Comment: The first picture would not work for the required application since it's made of one piece. The variant of the shaft collar that would work is called a  "two-piece shaft collar". The second one is actually called "split nut".

Comment: @Kevlar  Great catch!  Pasted wrong picture. I used the caddy threaded rod nut becaause that's what Granger called them.

Answer (score 2):

In the world of machining, a lathe uses a feature called a half-nut. It's two half-nuts mounted on a slide in which they are separated to disengage the carriage from the lead screw, or brought closer together to engage the carriage to the lead screw. This stops or starts movement of the cutting tool on the work piece.

[image: lathe half nut]

The image above comes from [Mini-lathe.com website](http://www.mini-lathe.com/Mini_lathe/Features/features_2.htm) and shows a crude version, which is all that is needed to accomplish the above-described task. The release/activation mechanism moves the upper half downward onto the lead screw (aka threaded rod, specialty version) and the lower half upward.

There are as many versions of half-nuts as there are versions of lathes using them.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a threaded tube that has been cut in half length-wise and clamped or joined to the threaded section with nuts and bolts or welded as suitable.

Answer (score 0):

try a sliding speed nut: [image]
very easy to slide along threaded rod    https://www.leevalley.com/en-ca/shop/hardware/jig-and-fixture-parts/101377-1-4-20-and-5-16-18-brass-speed-nuts

Comment: The question was, "*Does there exist any type of Nut, that can be screwed on a threaded rod that can slipped in **without having to go to the ends of the threaded rod**? Your suggestion has to go on via the end of the rod. See the accepted answer for what the OP was looking for. Also, you should at least post an image of what you are referring to so that the answer still makes sense when the link dies. Welcome to E.SE.